# ASP anchor Tag Helper for Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

How do you declare the anchor element using Tag Helpers to call this method using the custom route?

```
    [HttpGet("Account/{accountID}")]
    public IActionResult Perormance(string accountID) {
        return View(new AccountPerformance(accountID));
    }
```

The following does not seem to work

```
    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Performance" asp-route-accountID="@account.AccountID">@account.Name</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expected to provide a valid action method name as the `asp-action` attribute value. Your action method name is  `Perormance` and you are passing `Performance` as the value of asp-action attribute.

It should work as long as you use the same name for the action method and the asp-action attribute value. So change your action method name to `Performance`.

```
[HttpGet("Account/{accountID}")]
public IActionResult Performance(string accountID) 
{
    return View(new AccountPerformance(accountID));
}
```